# Simple rating system

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, rating-system

I'm trying to do a rating system, but I got some problems.

here's my html:

```
                    <div id="div-stars1">                   
                        <img src="assets/imagens/star_empty_na.png" style="width: 25px" id="img-starsna">
                        <img src="assets/imagens/star_empty.png" style="width: 25px" class="img-stars" id="img-star1">
                        <img src="assets/imagens/star_empty.png" style="width: 25px" class="img-stars" id="img-star2">
                        <img src="assets/imagens/star_empty.png" style="width: 25px" class="img-stars" id="img-star3">
                        <img src="assets/imagens/star_empty.png" style="width: 25px" class="img-stars" id="img-star4">
                        <img src="assets/imagens/star_empty.png" style="width: 25px" class="img-stars" id="img-star5">                              
                    </div>

                    <div id="div-stars2">                   
                        <img src="assets/imagens/star_empty_na.png" style="width: 25px" id="img-starsna">
                        <img src="assets/imagens/star_empty.png" style="width: 25px" class="img-stars" id="img-star6">
                        <img src="assets/imagens/star_empty.png" style="width: 25px" class="img-stars" id="img-star7">
                        <img src="assets/imagens/star_empty.png" style="width: 25px" class="img-stars" id="img-star8">
                        <img src="assets/imagens/star_empty.png" style="width: 25px" class="img-stars" id="img-star9">
                        <img src="assets/imagens/star_empty.png" style="width: 25px" class="img-stars" id="img-star10">                             
                    </div>
```

Well, I'll need to have several block codes like this, but I wouldn't like to have many functions to this (# div-stars3, # div-stars4 ... #divstars20). Yes, there are many questions from my poll, but I do not want to repeat code, I mean, I do not want to code any of the same things ($ ("# div-stars1").mouseover (function () {....}), $ ("# div-stars2").mouseover (function () {....}), $ ("# div-stars3")..... So, I'd like some advice from wich way to go. I care for a clean, lean and dynamic code.

I did the rating system just with one block code div, no more than one. Now I need to do with many block codes, many questions with many stars, each one answering for your `<div>`

Thanks.

Comment: HI @jbernardo, Lea Verou has a tutorial to do this using css. you might get some ideas from: [link to article](http://lea.verou.me/2011/08/accessible-star-rating-widget-with-pure-css/)

Comment: Heres a fiddle link to the css version [https://jsfiddle.net/bgibson/q852ohww/](https://jsfiddle.net/bgibson/q852ohww/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a class to all divs and use the [Class Selector](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/):

```
$( ".class" ).on( "mouseover", function() {
  ...
});
```

If you don't want to use classes, you might want to do what @John Wu suggested. It works the same.

Then, to know which div triggered the function, you can use [event.target](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/):

```
$( ".class" ).on( "mouseover", function() {
  // alert the id of the hovered div
  alert( event.target.id );
});
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks. From this way indicated, my code is great, it works and I can understand it clearly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply a handler to multiple DIVs that have the same name except for the number at the end, you could the ["starts with" selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$("DIV[ID^='divstars']").mouseover(etc.)
```

Comment: I don't know if we are talking about the similar thing, but I've tried to use class 'img-stars' from img, but for example, when the event is mouseover, all the stars are filled up, of course, all imagens has the same class. So, I've tried search about number of the elements (DOM node, index), lol, I'm a little lost.

Comment: So the handler is binding OK, but your code is hitting everything instead of the specific control.  If that is the case, you need to use `event.target.id` as atcastroviejo suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code for getting a star based rating system.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Font Awesome Icon Library -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <style>
    #priorityFlag {
      color: rgb(241, 241, 70);
      font-size: 1em;
      padding: 0.25em;
      border-width: 1px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
    
    .fa-star {}
    
    .fa-star:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .checkedStar {
      color: rgb(248, 248, 41);
    }
    
    #ratingBox {
      width: 150px;
    }
    
    #ratinngBox::after {
      content: '';
      display: block;
      clear: both;
    }
    
    #starsBox {
      
      float: left;
      width: 70%;
    }
    
    #flagBox {
      width: 30%;
      float: right;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <h2>Star Rating</h2>
  <div id="ratingBox">
    <div id="starsBox">
      <span class="fa fa-star checkedStar" data-priority-value="0" data-status-marked="true"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-star" data-priority-value="1" data-status-marked="false"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-star" data-priority-value="2" data-status-marked="false"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-star" data-priority-value="3" data-status-marked="false"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-star" data-priority-value="4" data-status-marked="false"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="flagBox">
      <span class="fa fa-flag" id="priorityFlag"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    var stars = document.getElementsByClassName("fa-star");
    // console.log("obj of strs array",stars);
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(stars, (star) => star.addEventListener("click", setPriority));

    var rateColors = ['rgb(248, 248, 41)', 'gold', 'orange', 'darkorange', 'red'];
    var flag = document.getElementById("priorityFlag");


    function setPriority(event) {
      var star = event.srcElement;
      var priority = star.getAttribute("data-priority-value");
      //  console.log("proirity is ",priority);
      var index = priority;

      var markedStar = star.getAttribute("data-status-marked");
      // console.log("is this star marked status",markedStar,"index is ",index);
      if (markedStar == "false")
        markStar(index);
      else //if(markedStar=="true")
        unMarkStar(index);
      // else
      // console.log("extremly wrong happening in setPriority function");
    }

    function markStar(index) {

      for (let i = 0; i <= index; i++) {
        stars[i].style.color = rateColors[index];
        // console.log("inside markStar marking "+i+" th star marked");
        stars[i].setAttribute("data-status-marked", "true");

        // console.log("true marked obj",stars[i],"marked status is",stars[i].getAttribute("data-status-marked"));
      }
      updateFlag(index);
    }

    function unMarkStar(index) {
      for (let i = 1; i < stars.length; i++) {
        // console.log("marking",`${i}`,stars[i]);
        stars[i].style.color = 'black';
        stars[i].setAttribute("data-status-marked", "false");
      }
      // console.log("inside umMarkStar",index,` nextline is markStar(${index})false`);
      markStar(index);

    }

    function updateFlag(index) {

      // console.log("update flag acc to",index,rateColors[index]);//updating flag color to this index of flagColors array
      flag.style.color = rateColors[index];
      flag.style.borderColor = rateColors[index];


    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```